# Decomposition of positive rationals as a series (uniqueness part)

Tags: real-analysis

This is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500931/every-positive-rational-number-x-can-be-expressed-in-the-form-sum-k-1n-f) but I'm having troubles with the uniqueness part (there's some explanation on how to prove the uniqueness part but honestly I don't understand it). Here's the claim and my attempt

> Any positive rational number $r$ can be expressed in exaclty one way in the form
>   $$ r = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j/j!$$ where $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are integers such that
>   $a_1\geq0$, $0\leq a_j <j$ for $2\leq j \leq n$ and $a_n\neq 0$.

As this is an exercise from [Stromberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440) I think the uniqueness part must have two prove two facts:

First: Let $r = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j/j! = \sum_{j=1}^m b_j/j!$ with $n<m$. At this point I compute

$$
0 = (a_1 - b_1)/1! + (a_2 - b_2)/2! + \dots + (a_n - b_n)/n!+b_{n+1}/(n+1)!+\dots+b_m/m! \neq 0
$$

because at least $b_m\neq0$ by hypothesis and this contradiction yields $n=m$ (is this correct?).

Second: With $r = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j/j! = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j/j!$ assume $a_j\neq b_j$ for some $j$ and let $s$ be the largest such $j$: say $a_s<b_s$. Here again

$$
0=\sum_{j=0}^s (a_j-b_j)/j!=\dots
$$

After this I don't know how to continue and arise a contradiction...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more general theorem
which I proved over 50 years ago.

Let $(B_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}
$
be an increasing sequence of positive integers
with
$B_1 > 1$.

Then every real $0 \le r < 1$
can be represented in the form
$r
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} d_n/B_n
$
where the $d_n$
are integers such that
$0 \le d_n \lt B_{n+1}/B_n
$
and the representation
is unique
for all $r$
 if and only if
$B_n | B_{n+1}$
for all $n$.

"unique" means that
if a number has
two representations then
one is terminating
and the other replaces the last digit
$d_n$
with
$d_n-1, m_{m+1}, m_{n+2}, ...
$
where
$m_n$ is the max value
$d_n$ can be,
$m_n
= \lceil B_{n+1}/B_n \rceil -1
$.
An example is
$0.1 = 0.09999....$.

This is why
decimal, binary, and factorial representations
are unique.

I'll look and see if I still have that writeup.
Until then, consider this an exercise.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm still far from generalizing this simple statement.  I don't think there's much trouble in what I'm doing, I just feel I'm lost in a subtle step of the proof. If you can clean up my proof and point out if it's right or wrong I would reconsider your answer.

Comment: can you provide an answer? I need this as well