# every real number can be expressed as a sum of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Every positive real number $x_1$ is, in one and only one way, expressible in the form: $$x_1 = a_1
+{a_2\over2!}+{a_3\over3!}+\cdots$$
where $a_n$ is a non-negative integer with $a_n \le n-1$ for $n > 1$ subject to the condition of not being $=n-1$ for every $n$ after a definite $n_0$. If $x_1$ is rational, and only then, the series terminates. For rational $x_1$ there's already an answer here [Every positive rational number $x$ can be expressed in the form $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k!}$ with $ a_k≤ k − 1$ for $k ≥ 2$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500931/every-positive-rational-number-x-can-be-expressed-in-the-form-sum-k-1n-f) but I don't understand the uniqueness part. How to generalize this to real numbers?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you do not understand about the uniqueness part? E.g.  Which sentence did you find confusing? Which sentence do you not agree with?

Comment: @Calvin Lin I don't see how the hint given by Brian Scott can be useful

Comment: @CalvinLin also can you elaborate your answer about uniqueness?

Comment: For $a_1 = 0$, what is the largest value you can get with a sum up to the $1/n!$ term? That is, what is $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k-1}{k!}\text{?}$$ So if $x = a_1 + a_2/2!+\ldots$ and $x = b_1 + b_2/2!+\ldots$, is it possible for $b_1 > a_1$?

Comment: if the sum is finite no, for $a_1$ is the integer part of $x$ and similarly $b_1$. In fact one can find a formula for $a_k$. The problem is when the sum is infinite.