# Let $r$ be a rational no. with $0<r<1$. Then $r$ can be expressed as a sum of reciprocals of finitely many distinct positive integers

Tags: number-theory, fractions

Let $r$ be a rational no. with $0<r<1$. Then $r$ can be expressed as a sum of reciprocals of finitely many distinct positive integers . Show that this is true even for $r>1$.

If there is a particular theorem or an article on this please share..

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/prove-that-any-rational-can-be-expressed-in-the-form-sum-limits-k-1n-frac

Comment: I see three algorithms there, but will it be rigorous to state them only?

Comment: I see a proof there.