# Expressing a Fraction in Simplest form

Tags: number-theory, fractions

I have given a fraction in the form of $p/q$ , i want to express the given fraction as sum of series which is in the form of $1/x$ and $x$ is odd.
i.e

$$ p/q = 1/x + 1/y+ 1/z+1/l/s $$
such that denominator is an odd number.

One trival way is to express $p/q = 1/q+1/q+1/q+....$($p$ times ).  but i want length of the series to less than $p$.

How to do that ?

Comment: Greedy Egyptian algorithm might do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that any rational can be expressed in the form $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{a_k}}$, $a_k\in\mathbb N^*$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/prove-that-any-rational-can-be-expressed-in-the-form-sum-limits-k-1n-frac)

Comment: Not a duplicate exactly, as in this post denominators required to be odd.

Comment: Can't be less terms than $p$ if $p=1$.

Comment: For some fractions $p/q$ it can be done with less than $p$ terms, but based on some empirical tests, whenever it can be done with less than $p$ terms, a greedy odd algorithm will find such a representation with the least number of terms.