# Represent improper fraction as a sum of unique unit fractions

Tags: number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

Is it possible to represent an improper fraction as a finite sum of unique unit fractions ([Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction))?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205099/expressing-a-fraction-in-simplest-form).

Comment: You know the result for rational numbers less than $1$ and you ask if it holds above $1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you for the link, but the answer provided works for `0 < x < 1`, whereas I am asking for improper fractions.

Comment: @lulu, yes, that's exactly what I am asking, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Start with $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$, $\alpha >1$.  Then let $n$ be the greatest integer such that $$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i<\alpha $$

Of course $n$ exists because the infinite Harmonic series diverges.

It follows that $\alpha - H_n<\frac 1n$  so none of the fractions in the standard Egyptian decomposition of $\alpha - H_n$ can appear in $H_n$.

Comment: Thank you, it did not occur to me that uniqueness can be proven by Harmonic series too!

Comment: This doesn't show uniqueness!  Uniqueness isn't even true... $\frac 32 = 1 +\frac 12=1+\frac 13 +\frac 16$

Comment: Or did you mean that each of the fractions that appears is guaranteed to occur only once?  That is true (and is demonstrated by what I wrote).

Comment: Yes, I meant that in this representation each fraction occurs only once